# Typescript: wrong generic inference with function default parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to add types to a function that takes a Promise and, optionally, a modifier.

The function is similar to this:

```js
const identity = <T>(v: T) => v;

const asyncWrapper = async <
  PromiseReturn,
  ModifierReturn = PromiseReturn
>(
  asyncAction: () => Promise<PromiseReturn>,
  modifier: (original: PromiseReturn) => ModifierReturn = identity
) => {
  const promiseResult = await asyncAction();
  return modifier(promiseResult);
};
```

The goal is: **call a promise. If the optional modifier is passed, modify the promise result, otherwise return just the promise result**.

But unfortunately `modifier` raises the following type error:

```
Type '<T>(v: T) => T' is not assignable to type '(original: PromiseReturn) => ModifierReturn'.
  Type 'PromiseReturn' is not assignable to type 'ModifierReturn'.
    'ModifierReturn' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'PromiseReturn'.
```

I think to undestand that the error is about `identity` being of type `a -> a` whilst modifier is of type `a -> b`, but I don't understand *why* it is raised, because `ModifierReturn` is generic and, in the case of `identity` it is equal to `a`. Basically, `a -> ModifierReturn` is equal to `a -> a` when I use `identity`.

If I cast `identity` like this:

```js
  modifier: (original: PromiseReturn) => ModifierReturn = identity<PromiseReturn> as any
```

everything works fine.

I am struggling to understand why typescript is not able to infer these types automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If TypeScript would allow this, then nothing will prevent you to write something like the following:

```
const ps = asyncWrapper<number, string>(() => Promise.resolve(2));
//    ^? Promise<string>
```

Beacuse, as TS tells you, `ModifierReturn` could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to `PromiseReturn`.

But that would be unsound, actually the promise contains a `number`, not a `string`.